# Concatenate two regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to concatenate two reqexp while replace process. Its working fine one by one replace. Please guide.

```
var content = `series onPsychologyOutlineHistorySubfields<button type="button" class="mw-collapsible-toggle mw-collapsible-toggle-default" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">hide</button>Basic typesAbnormalBehavioralBehavioral geneticsBiologicalCognitive/CognitivismComparativeCross-culturalCulturalDevelopmentalDifferentialEvolutionaryExperimentalMathematicalNeuropsychologyPersonalityPositivePsychodynamicPsychometricsQuantitativeSocial<button type="button" class="mw-collapsible-toggle mw-collapsible-toggle-default" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">hide</button>Applied psychologyApplied behavior analysisClinicalCommunityConsumerCounselingCriticalEducationalEnvironmentalErgonomicsFoodForensicHealthHumanisticIndustrial and organizationalLegalMedicalMilitaryMusicOccupational healthPoliticalPsychometricsReligionSchoolSportTraffic<button type="button" class="mw-collapsible-toggle mw-collapsible-toggle-default" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">hide</button>ListsDisciplinesOrganizationsPsychologistsPsychotherapiesResearch methodsTheoriesTimelineTopics<img alt="" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Psi2.svg/16px-Psi2.svg.png" decoding="async" width="16" height="16" class="mw-file-element" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Psi2.svg/24px-Psi2.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Psi2.svg/32px-Psi2.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="100" data-file-height="100"> Psychology portalvte<p><b>Psychology</b> is the study of mind and behavior in humans and non-humans. Psychology includes the study of</p>`;


var regex1= /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
var reqex2= /<img[^>]*>/g;


content = content.replace(regex1, "");

content = content.replace(regex2, "");
```

Comment: Aside: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using a OR (`|`) operator:

```
var content = "Your big thing"
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)|(<img[^>]*>)/ig;
content = content.replace(regex, "");
```

Hope this helps!